# Event Binding Using { }

Tags: c#, wpf, events, binding

I am creating a `TextBox` in code-behind.

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
```

I also have a function:

```
private void TextBox_Focus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // does something
}
```

I want to bind `TextBox_Focus` to `TextBox.GotFocus`.

Rather than setting each property individually like so

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Width = 100;
textBox.Height = 25;
textBox.Background = Brushes.White;
textBox.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
textBox.GotFocus += TextBox_Focus;
```

I prefer using braces (curly brackets) `{}`:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox()
{
   Width = 100,
   Height = 25,
   Background = Brushes.White,
   Foreground = Brushes.Blue
};
```

However, when I use the braces method, I am unable to bind to events.

I have tried doing the following, but to no avail...

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox()
{
   Width = 100,
   Height = 25,
   Background = Brushes.White,
   Foreground = Brushes.Blue,
   this.GotFocus += TextBox_Focus
};
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to event bind using the braces (`{}`) method?

**Update:**
The element is being created dynamically, so I cannot use XAML.

Comment: The "braces method" is an object initializer, which should help you find [other questions that ask the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993601/assigning-events-in-object-initializer)

Comment: Your question starts up by saying `I am creating a TextBox in code-behind. ` - Which is generally a really bad practice unless you have a GOOD reason for that. Can you explain what you need so I can tell you the right way to implement it in WPF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993601/assigning-events-in-object-initializer

Comment: @HighCore I wanted to simplify the example so I don't use excessive code. In my real example, I have a ListBox that users edit.  When they click "Add", it creates, using code behind, an element and binds it to the list items.

Comment: You could just use bindings and XAML, unless the GotFocus event is also variable.

Comment: The answer here has some additional info that might be interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993601/assigning-events-in-object-initializer

Comment: @keyboardP you are the 3rd one to post that link hah

Comment: @Dom you should use XAML for that, and not create UI elements in code ala-winforms. Even if it's "dynamic". WPF's idea of dynamic differs a lot from traditional pseudo-UI frameworks.

Comment: @NickFreeman - *facepalm* lol. Just goes to show how good it is! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [Object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) only work to set properties or fields. You're trying to subscribe to an event, which isn't supported in Object initializer syntax.

As other commenters are saying, XAML is the best way to initialize WPF controls.

Apparently Mono though supports what you're asking for. See: [Initializing events with initializer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751837/initializing-events-with-initializer-syntax)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'll also look into `Mono C#`. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Xaml, you'll find it is quite flexible.
And also kinda WPF's thing.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox"
         Width="100"
         Height="25"
         Background="White"
         Foreground="Blue"
         GotFocus="TextBox_Focus" />
```

As per your comment, you can do what you wish like so:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox Text="{Binding }"
                           Width="100"
                           Height="25"
                           Background="White"
                           Foreground="Blue"
                           GotFocus="TextBox_Focus" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

If you make your Collection an `ObservableCollection<T>` when you add an item to the collection it will update your list box for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I wish I could use XAML, however, the element needs to be created dynamically.

Comment: You can still add items dynamically using XAML. Code behind isn't a magical entity.

Comment: What are you trying to generate? Is it a collection of items, because then a `DataTemplate` would be the way to go forward.

Comment: @ywm The XAML is all turned into code eventually.  If it's quicker or easier in a particular context then you can use it, if it's not (even if it's possible) then don't.

Comment: Granted, but the XAML is about the same really in this case. But it fits the paradigm that others would expect when they come to maintain your WPF application.

Answer (score -3):

Try 
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox),TextBox.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(yourMethod());

Comment: How is this preferable to subscribing to the event through `object.Event += eventhandler`?  Also, still couldn't be done through an object initializer, so doesn't' answer the question.