# Setting SelectionChanged property from code

Tags: wpf

I have a dynamically created ComboBox that I need to set the SelectionChanged property for. How can I do this from code?

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox()
{
    Background = Brushes.GhostWhite,
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Gainsboro,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
    Margin = new Thickness(10),
    ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>(list),
    SelectionChanged = "comboBox_SelectionChanged" //SelectionChanged is not a valid property
};
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to attach a SelectionChanged event handler like this:

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox { ... };
comboBox.SelectionChanged += comboBox_SelectionChanged;
```

The above assumes that there is a handler method like

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectionChanged` is not a property, it is an event. You are trying to attach event handler to an event using object initializer syntax, and .NET doesn't seems to support that.

Here are some related questions :

- [Initializing events with initializer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751837/initializing-events-with-initializer-syntax)
- [Assigning events in object initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993601/assigning-events-in-object-initializer)