# C# 6 Event Initializers

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I'm using C# 6.0 in VS Community

1. Where event initializers removed from c# 6.0 & any idea why the code below doesn't work?
2. Where can I get an updated list of not just latest features and what was recently removed from C# 6.0?

This doesn't compile for me. Specifically on line with 'Barking += (o, e)...'

```
    EventHandler<EventArgs> log = (o, e) => Console.Write("woof");
    var dog = new Dog()
    {
        Age = 3,
        Barking += (o, e) => Console.Write("woof");
    };

    class Dog
    {
        public void Bark() {
            if (Barking != null) {
                Barking(this,new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        public int Age { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "nameless";    
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Barking;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, please.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, event initializers were removed. The current feature status can be seen here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14

Comment: There is a ugly workaround for this: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751837/initializing-events-with-initializer-syntax)