# setup event handlers during constructor

Tags: c#, event-handling, initialization

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951619/add-event-handler-during-object-initialization) question.

If I understood right. It's impossible to do something like

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout ()
{
    MouseClick += myMouseClickHandler
}
```

But what is preferred solution to setup this handler?

Make new class inherited from `TableLayout` and ...

...adding reference to handler to the constructor.

...create public standalone method like `SetupSomeEventHandler(MouseEventHandler meh)`

...or maybe something more elegant solution exist?

Comment: Ok, I just add handler after constructor. I'll hope that in future standards C# may compile code like i wrote at start.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to set it in the constructor you can do this.

**WPF Version**

```
public class TableLayout 
{
    public TableLayout()
    {
    }
    public TableLayout (Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> clickHandler)
    {
        MouseClick += clickHandler;
    }
}
```

**WinForms Version**

```
public class TableLayout 
{
    public TableLayout()
    {
    }
    public TableLayout (Action<object, EventArgs> clickHandler)
    {
        MouseClick += clickHandler;
    }
}
```

Then

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout (myMouseClickHandler);
```

Comment: Why are you using `Func<object, EventArgs> clickHandler`? Handlers are actions and don't return values. Besides there are already appropriate delegates already defined.

Comment: Do you think you should use `MouseEventHandler` & `RoutedEventHandler`? Right now your code doesn't compile. Please test both solutions before posting.

Comment: @Enigmativity Trying to help to OP, maybe this does not works 100% because you are right I did ot compiled it but can guide to OP. Im trying to help him not you Im sorry.

Comment: @Enigmativity Btw if you were trying to help, you can edit my question or post another answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that you're using WinForms and that if I show you what to do with a `Form` that you'll be able to apply it to your `TableLayout` class.

Here's what you need to do:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(MouseEventHandler handler)
        : this()
    {
        this.MouseClick += handler;
    }
}
```

When creating this form I can do this:

```
var form1 = new Form1((s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("You clicked me!"); })
```

In your case this would look like this:

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(myMouseClickHandler);
```