# c# event handler for multiple dynamically created control

Tags: c#, event-handling, controls, dynamically-generated

I have a loop that could create 1 or maybe 10 or maybe 584575 (example, not actually true) `FlowLayoutPanels`. For all these panels I want a hover event handler, or maybe later another type of event handler but for now only hover.

How can I make this happen for *multiple* same type created controls?

```
FlowLayoutPanel finalResult_panel = new FlowLayoutPanel{
       FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
       BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
       Name = "result_flowLayoutPanel" + i,
       Size = new System.Drawing.Size(790, 72),
       TabIndex = i,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the handler like this

```
finalResult_panel.MouseHover += panel_MouseHover;

private void panel_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}
```

Alternatively you can create an anonymous delegate

```
finalResult_panel_MouseHover += (s,e) => {
                                            //event code 
                                         };
```

These will attach the same handlers to every panel so if you need to differentiate, you can do that in the handler itself (using the `sender` property) or somehow differentiate before attaching the handler.

Comment: When trying your first option I get `Invalid initializer member declarator' and i dont exactly know how to use your alternative option.

Comment: You need to put it after the code you have, not inside the object initalizer.

Comment: Alright that works thanks! Why cant it be in the object initializer? And could   explain the alternative method? I dont understand how to implement.

Comment: I don't know why there isn't syntactic sugar to allow events in the object initializer (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993601/assigning-events-in-object-initializer). The second method is an anonymous function that uses a lambda expression. Where I've put `event code` is where the code goes for the handler. There's more information here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx