# Add Mousedown event in new CheckBox() instance

Tags: c#

Briefly, my app adds checkboxes programmatically into a flowlayoutpanel named "fp".

```
fp.Controls.Add(new CheckBox() { Name = "cb1", Text = "New Checkbox", Checked = true, AutoSize = true, AllowDrop = true });
```

i'm stuck trying to add a mouseclick event inside that new Checkbox instance. I tried adding the line below into the code above.

```
this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(cbox_MouseDown);
```

But I get **Invalid initializer member declarator**

I also tried to add this:

```
((CheckBox)(this.Controls.Find("cb1", false))[0]).MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(cbox_MouseDown);
```

before adding the new checkbox instance but it does not work either.

I could highly appreciate a way to insert the event directly into the new CheckBox() instance .

Thank you guys <3

Comment: Please post a multi-line code example where you tried to do `this.MouseDown += new MouseE...` because your post is unclear about how you did it. Obviously putting it on the line below `fp.Controls.Add` isn't going to work because `this` is _not_ the `CheckBox`.

Comment: Also, you should use `Click` instead of `MouseDown`. This is because `MouseDown` is only raised when Windows detects an actual physical mouse button press, whereas the `Click` event is raised when the user toggles a checkbox using alternative means, such as tapping the space-bar when the checkbox has focus. The same applies to `Button.Click` too. (Fun fact: `CheckBox` **is** actually a Button: `class CheckBox : ButtonBase`).

Comment: Are you asking how to use the "Object and Collection Initializers" syntax to contextually set the event handler on the newly created CheckBox? Are you not able to use a CheckBox variable?

Comment: The code added the box to the FlowLayoutPanel, searching the *form's* controls is not going to find it.  So either this.Controls.Find("cb1", true) or the more sensible fp.Controls.Find("cb1", false).  Or the ultimately sensible var box = new Checkbox() {...} so you can simply use box.MouseDown +=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [C#'s Object-Initializer syntax does not support events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993601/assigning-events-in-object-initializer).

  - C#'s Object-Initializers have a lot of other shortcomings too, I'm not a fan of them (horrible debugging, broken line-numbers in stack-traces, it ignores `IDisposable` when an exception is thrown, you can't use it with an existing object, often takes up more lines-of-code than otherwise, etc).
- However, you can define a new extension-method for `ControlsCollection` which will add the event-handler for you.

Like so:

**MyExtensions.cs**:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void AddWithClickHandler( this ControlsCollection ctrls, EventHandler onClickHandler, CheckBox newCheckBox )
    {
        newCheckBox.Click += onClickHandler;
        ctrls.Add( newCheckBox );
    }
}
```

**MyForm.cs**:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private readonly EventHandler onClickHandler;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //

        this.onClickHandler = new EventHandler( this.cbox_MouseDown );
    }

    private void cbox_MouseDown( Object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // 
    }
    
    private Int32 checkboxCount = 0;
    private String GetNewCheckboxName()
    {
        this.checkboxCount += 1;
        return "cb" + this.checkboxCount.ToString("d");
    }

    public void AddCheckboxes()
    {
        this.fp.Controls.AddWithClickHandler( onClickHandler, new CheckBox() { Name = this.GetNewCheckboxName(), Text = "New Checkbox", Checked = true, AutoSize = true, AllowDrop = true } );

        this.fp.Controls.AddWithClickHandler( onClickHandler, new CheckBox() { Name = this.GetNewCheckboxName(), Text = "New Checkbox", Checked = true, AutoSize = true, AllowDrop = true } );

        this.fp.Controls.AddWithClickHandler( onClickHandler, new CheckBox() { Name = this.GetNewCheckboxName(), Text = "New Checkbox", Checked = true, AutoSize = true, AllowDrop = true } );
    }
}
```

---

**Note that:**

- In my code, the `MyForm` class only ever creates a single `EventHandler` instance (using `new EventHandler`), [this is important as you need to allow code to *de-register* (i.e. remove) event-handlers to prevent memory-leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526829/why-and-how-to-avoid-event-handler-memory-leaks).

  - Unfortunately you cannot remove event-handlers registered using the shorthand syntax like this: `obj.Click += this.OnClickMethod;`
  - Nor can you remove event-handlers implemented as lambda-methods, e.g. `obj.Click += ( obj, sender ) => this.DoSomething();`
- Control Names need to be unique, so rather than hardcoding strings like `"cb1"` and `"cb2"`, unique names for each and every checkbox is generated by the `GetNewCheckboxName()` method.

Comment: Omg Dude! Exactly and literally what I needed. Why stuff like this I can never find in MSDN or Google.. It's ok for me to register a single event and not be able to remove it. Thank you so much Dai! Marked as answer and +1.